# Gif background is not showing on safari (iPhone)

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari

I have a gif as a background for the first div on my [website](http://staging.wearecalm.co.uk). For some reason, the background doesn't appear on the safari (mobile) but it works fine on every other browser on mobile. The gif also appears on the safari on a desktop.

My CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px){
.introsection {
    background-size: 100% !important;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
}
}

.introsection {
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url('../../assets/img/calm_logo.gif') no-repeat center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Comment: Can you try to add quote arround your link `background: url("../../assets/img/calm_logo.gif")` ? (I am not sure if that will work, I know that safari has a stricter syntax than other browsers

Comment: @PascalGoldbach I have added the speech marks. Does it work? I don't have an iPhone on me.

Comment: Sorry, I also don't have an iPhone on me right now